# Give table's every side a different color via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a 2 rows and 4 columns table via FlexTable, and I want to give this table's every side a different color with Google Apps Script. How could I do? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.setColumnStyle(...)` or `.setStyleAttribute(...)` read a bit the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/flex-table)

Very bad question, if i could i would rate it down.